# no record action button in office script

Tags: office-scripts

I am trying to identify where the **[Record Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/tutorials/excel-tutorial)** button is on Ms Excel office script. There is no such button.

[image]

What I've tried:

1. I looked all of the available command and there is no Record Action. Only Record Macro.
   [image]

how do I find the Record Action button/command?

Comment: Your second screenshot is redundant, it's not in the desktop version.  However, why it's not on your web version of Excel is beyond me.

Comment: I didn't even know that it should be in the online version. I just noticed the new Automate on my excel desktop and I was surprised. Apparently, the tutorial is still too fresh. @Skin

Comment: Ohhhhh ok. There you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on @skin 's comment, I overlooked a simple detail on [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/tutorials/excel-tutorial)

> This tutorial teaches you the basics of recording, editing, and writing an Office Script for **Excel on the web**

record action available on the web, not desktop app.

Comment: I should make it more obvious that you currently need Excel on the web for the Action Recorder. Thanks for calling this out.

Answer (score 1):

Recording actions with Office Scripts was [recently released](https://insider.office.com/en-us/blog/record-worksheet-actions-using-office-scripts-in-excel) to Office Insiders. According to [their roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=office%2Cscripts), it's slated for general availability in March.